# Changing css using javascript works inline but not from header

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div area that I want to change the css after the page loads. My HTML looks like the following

```
<div class='myArea'>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
          $('.myArea').css('background-color',"red");
</script>
```

And it works. But if I move this to an external js file and reference the js file from the header, this doesn't work. The following is the js code in the external file -

```
function init(){
      $('.myArea').css('background-color',"blue");

  }
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

What might be the reason behind this

Comment: Are you executing your JavaScript before the page has finished loading? And if you're using jQuery, which it looks like, why are you using `window.addEventListener('load', init, false);`?

Comment: Keep in mind that the reference to the external js file must be placed after the *JQuery* reference, because it uses it...

Comment: Thats what `$(document).ready(function() { .. })` is for

Comment: Put your script at the bottom of the body tag.  That will be 'after' the page loads.  Anything in the header is before the html content has loaded.

Comment: @j08691, I think adding the load event listener makes sure that the page finishes loading before the js execution, is it? In my production, I was not initially planning to use jquery, but will use the $ function as a utility function.

Comment: @LcSalazar, yes did just that.

Comment: @AndrewIce I want to know why using the event listener is not working? Since it is not throwing any exception on the console logs, I can only assume that it is fired properly.

Comment: @Brian, that worked. Thanks. So the question still remains, Why the method you mentioned is working and why the window.addEventListener is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to put the code inside jQuery document ready function, $() is a shortcut to that function:

```
$(function(){
    $('.myArea').css('background-color',"red");
});
```

Comment: Your solution works. Can you please explain, why the add event listener is not working and your solution working?

Comment: this is the same as using `ready()` you cant bind events to elements that havent been rendered. `ready()` is an event on the document that fires when the document has loaded. [read more here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Is as @Brian says, `$()` is a shortcut to `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead?:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('.myArea').css('background-color',"red");
}
```

Or, if you're already using jQuery, you could use their document ready(): http://api.jquery.com/ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.myArea').css('background-color',"red");
});
```